# How To Start A Session Using Another Field Name From DatabasE?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I have a session registered from previous webpages in my website called 'name'. this is one of my fields in my database and was registered as a session after a person has logged into one section out of the many login screens. How do i go about changing this session variable? my code is as follows:

```
    <?php

$secret_anwser=$_POST['secret_anwser'];
$secret_anwser = stripslashes($secret_anwser);
$secret_anwser = mysql_real_escape_string($secret_anwser);

$sql="SELECT * FROM public WHERE secret_anwser ='$secret_anwser' AND active = 'activated' AND name = '". $_SESSION['name']."'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

header("location:votenow.php");
}
?>
```

i have a table in my database with a field called 'ni'. how would i register this session instead of the current 'name' session before redirecting on the votenow.php page?

thanks in advance

Comment: are you using session_register() ?

Comment: yes i am using session_register()

Comment: see below, you shouldn't be that function is depreciated, see the manual entry for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by register, if your still using session_register() you shouldn't be. You can simply read and write the $_SESSION array directly as long as you have stated the sessions (session_start) on the page.

in responce to comment - the same why you change any variable.

```
$_SESSION['xxxx']='yyyyy';
```

Comment: yh but how do i change the session from 'name' to 'ni'? whats the code for that...

Comment: lol im not explaining myself clearly. basically from previous pages, iv passed over this session variable of 'name'. now i dont want to pass the same variable onto votenow.php and seeing that the code above is a select statment of a secret_anwser, how would i possibly get a field called 'ni' to become my new session even though my sql statment does not mention anything about ni?

Comment: if *ni* is a field name in the *public* table of the db then you just populate the session array with the value from the query you have above.

Comment: ok thank you. i have one last question. this is got nothing to do with session variables or anything. I have a an if and else statement and i want to execute a select query in the echo part of the else bit. is that possible?

Comment: "execute a select query in the echo part " makes no sense, you can execute the query based on a condition, *and* echo something before or after the query based on the same condition; at least I think that is what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

[php.net](http://php.net) has substantial information on php and how to work with [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)